# Can I safely remove wildfly-stdout file?

Tags: wildfly

I have an application that is on Wildfly 10.1.0.Final.

In the folder \standalone\log there's this file:

wildfly-stdout.YYYY-MM-DD

The file is huge. Several GB.

Can I safely remove this file?

Need to free up space on the server.

Guess if I do that it will start a new empty one.

Just wanted to confirm.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that and it will surely start a new one.

Basically the file contains all messages sent to stdout/console by WildFly and that is also the reason why it could grow pretty large if you are logging on a more detailed level.

I would consider it good practice to regularly clean up old log files by a scheduled task (maybe the ones older than 2 months or so).